# How to move a-entities relative to center of the viewport [with object3D.position.set(x, y, z) ]

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm using a-frame to create a scene with a box that moves according to a sine function, but the box doesn't show up inside the viewport.

I already tried to update the box position by changing the "position" attribute and resetting the box.object3D.position.

**HTML file**

```
<a-scene log="hello scene">
<a-assets>
  <img id="boxTexture" src="https://i.imgur.com/mYmmbrp.jpg">
</a-assets>

<a-box src="#boxTexture" position="0 0 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5">
  <!-- <a-animation attribute="position" to="0 2.2 -5" direction="alternate" dur="2000"
    repeat="indefinite"></a-animation> -->
  <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseenter" dur="300" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseleave" dur="300" to="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="click" dur="2000" to="360 405 45"></a-animation>
</a-box>

<a-camera>
  <a-cursor></a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

**JavaScript file**

```
// low frequency oscillator
function lfo(amp, freq, phase) {
  var date = new Date();
  var millis = 0.001 * date.getMilliseconds();
  var value = amp * Math.sin(millis * freq + phase);
  return value;
}

var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('a-box');

function moveBoxes() {
  // loop through all the boxes in the document
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    let x = lfo(1, 1, 0);
    let y = lfo(1, 1, 0.2);
    let z = lfo(1, 1, 0.7);
    boxes[i].object3D.position.set(x, y, z);
    //boxes[i].setAttribute("position", x+" "+y+" "+z);
  }
}
```

I'd except to see the box either on center of the scene or at least at the upper-left corner, but it's neither.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D viewport does not map to the 3D positions within the 3D scene.

The A-Frame mouse cursor maps mouse clicks to in-3D clicks. I'm not sure, but you might be able to use this sort of method to convert 2D X/Y coordinate to 3D coordinate at your specified distance: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/cursor.js#L213

But otherwise, I would just make something a child of the camera.

```
<a-entity camera>
  <a-box move-sin-wave-or-whatever-animation position="0 0 -1"></a-box>
</a-entity>
```